# Jersery ExceptionMapper does not intercept Exceptions thrown from Spring AspectJ annotated Aspects?

Tags: spring, jersey, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I use Spring annotation based AOP  for validating my Requests to the Jersery Resources.
I have implemented an Aspect as follows. But this XBBridgeException is not caught by Jersey ExceptionMapper , instead it throws from the Servlet Container.

Any tips on this?

```
@Aspect
public class RequestValidationAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.mycompany.facade.*.convertRequest(com.mycompany.BaseRequest+,..)) && args(req,..)")
    public void convertRequest(BaseRequest req) {

    }

    @Before("convertRequest(req)")
    public <T extends BaseRequest> void validateRequest(T req) throws XBBridgeException {

    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = null;
    try {
        violations = validator.validate(req, req.getValidatorGroup());
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ValidationException("{validation exception}");
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        List<String> msgList = new ArrayList<>();
        String msg;
        if (t instanceof ValidationException) {
        msg = "{bad request}";
        for (ConstraintViolation<T> violation : violations) {
            msgList.add(violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + " " + violation.getMessage());
        }
        } else {
        msg = "{request:" + req.toString() + "}";
        msgList.add("Runtime error");
        }
        throw new XBBridgeException("request validation exception", new RequestValidationException(msg, msgList, t));
    }
    }

    public Validator getValidator() {
    return validator;
    }

    public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

Problem was that my ExceptionMapper was typed to map XBBridgeExceptions ( ExceptionMapper ).

But Spring AOP aspect (RequestValidationAspect) throws UndeclaredThrowableException (which is a wrapper round XBBridgeException).
Since UndeclaredThrowableException is a RuntimeExpcetion it was not intercepted by my mapper.Solution was to write another ExceptionMapper for UndeclaredThrowableException exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if XBBridgeException is your own exception, can't seem to find any other references to it, but if it is, might be easier to just have it extend RuntimeException. This will prevent it from being wrapped in an UndeclaredThrowableException so you can then more naturally create the ExceptionMapper you wanted to create in the first place.